# R Run function Object Not Found

Tags: r

I know this has probably been answered a million times, but nothing I seem to do works.

I am running a function that I created, the function is stored in a R script, and I am sourcing and running the function in Rmarkdown.

```
example <- function(){
EP <- read_excel("filepath")
EP <- Project_EP_Rename(EP)
}
```

Error in MyPackage::Project_EP_Rename(EP) : object 'EP' not found.

I have tested by putting print(exists(EP)) right in between these lines and that printed TRUE. 
I am calling library(MyPackage) in the RMarkdown, and this script is located in a subdirectory of the Project file, so I thought that maybe the package wasn't being called. I check using print("MyPackage" %in% .packages()), reran and that came but true. I even tried changing the code to

```
EP <- MyPackage::Project_EP_Rename(EP)
```

That still didn't work. I ended up importing the file in the rmarkdown, and then running it through the function example(EP), and changed the code to this, and that worked.

```
example <- function(datafile){
EP <- datafile
EP <- Project_EP_Rename(EP)
}
```

Why exactly is this happening? I am very confused.

Comment: I was having a tough time following, but it seems like `read_excel()` is failing so then when it goes to the next line the object `EP` does not exist and it then kicks the error out.

Comment: I used print(exists(EP)) to see if it existed before running EP <- Project_EP_Rename(EP)), and it printed true. I should also state that if I run the code line by line it works perfectly fine. Its only when I call it as a function does it throw an error.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Second the reproducible example. Only other thing I can think of is that `MyPackage::Project_EP_Rename(EP)` itself is trying to use an object named `EP` that does not exist. So the function definition has named that single parameter something else, not `EP`. `Project_EP_Rename <- function(Not_EP) { ... tries to reference EP ...}`

Answer (score 0):

You created a function called `example` and not `Project_EP_Rename` in your example. But let's assume you have the specification of the function somewhere else in your script and `Project_EP_Rename` has one argument which is the input object (called `EP` in your case). If you don't create the `EP` object before you run the `Project_EP_Rename` correctly says `object 'EP' not found`.
Probably, running the `example` function instead of `Project_EP_Rename` would work as it first creates the `EP` object by `EP <- read_excel("filepath")` and then executes the `Project_EP_Rename` function.

By the way, in your case I don't see any reason why to create `example` function with no argument like you have at the beginning.